# Implied globals and the global object

Tags: javascript, global-variables, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to see a bit how implied globals work by experimenting with my console and plunker.

I'm creating a self-invoking function,

```
(function () {
  toto = 1;
})();
```

According to the book I'm reading,

> ... implied globals are technically not real variables,
>   but they are properties of the global object.

I'm trying to see if after this function call, I can access toto as a property of the global object - which, in the browser, is the `window`.

When I use `hasOwnProperty('toto')`, (by typing it in the console directly) I get false.
I figured I'd use `in`, and indeed, toto is "in" window (so, it's not in window itself but to a child object of it)

Can you shed some light?
Any idea how to use Chrome Web Tools in order to inspect the status of all variables declared at any given time?

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/tbn2mzar/ shows `true`.

Comment: I tried this in the Chrome console and both `"toto" in window` and `window.hasOwnProperty("toto")` return `true`. Can you give us more instructions on how to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Ok that's interesting. When you try to get this value from the Console window directly you get false.. that's strange?

Comment: What's your setup? If you're trying it in jsfiddle (or some other similar service) it puts the executed code in an iframe so the console's `window` is not the same as the iframe's `window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably runing your hasOwnProperty from console and you have the wrong frame selected.

I ran hasOwnProperty command in all of the frames that consist the plunker website and I get both true and false + in some frames toto is not even initialised (ReferenceError: toto is not defined).

Comment: is there a safer/more efficient way to see these things without console.logging?

Comment: You could check what properties does the global object have before and after execution, then make a difference of it - http://jsfiddle.net/d4rjxocb/